# Json in javascript

Tags: json

i haven't used json before . When i am using eval function on json response than it gives me 
error of missing ']'. My json is as follows

```
[{"name":"154.jpg","size":620888,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"\/active\/components\/com_mtree\/img\/listings\/o\/Tulips.jpg","thumbnail_url":"\/active\/components\/com_mtree\/img\/listings\/s\/Tulips.jpg","delete_url":"\/active\/components\/com_mtree\/img\/listings\/upload.php?file=Tulips.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]
```

is this any error in this json. in javascript i am using this

```
var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

Comment: Could you post your code with the actual call to eval in please?

Comment: No, the JSON sample is fine. Please give more context, i.e. a larger sample, and the JavaScipt code that's failing.

Answer (score 1):

> When i am using eval function

Don't do that. Use [a real JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

> it gives me error of missing ']'.

It shouldn't do, since the JSON is valid. You might be using it wrong, but you didn't show any code so it is hard to say. Using a real JSON parser is likely to help with that anyway.

Comment: var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');  i am using this

Answer (score 1):

Why are you prepending/appending brackets to it? As long as its a string, it works fine:

```
var x= '[{"name":"154.jpg","size":620888,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"\/active\/components\/com_mtree\/img\/listings\/o\/Tulips.jpg","thumbnail_url":"\/active\/components\/com_mtree\/img\/listings\/s\/Tulips.jpg","delete_url":"\/active\/components\/com_mtree\/img\/listings\/upload.php?file=Tulips.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE"}]';

alert(eval(x));
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gCE25/1/

This sort of thing is good if you are learning, however, I would echo @Quentin's sentiments - use a proper JSON Parser.